# Phantom Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line

Programmer here, be gentle.

I'm working in a MySQL database with only a single table, as shown by `show tables`:

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_widget_web |
+----------------------+
| widget_signups       |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

At some point earlier in development there might have been other tables as well, but for what we were doing we decided that we were probably over-architecting and nixed them.

I noticed the other day that auto-complete within mysql was not working properly in this database. When I am using the particular database and I type `SELECT * FROM widget<TAB>` I wasn't getting my good old auto-complete that I was used to. Double tabbing to see possible auto-completions yields:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM widget<TAB><TAB>
widget_date
widget_signups
[... columns on widget_signups ...]
```

Yet when I try to DROP this mysterious and previously deleted widget_date table, I predictably get errors saying the table doesn't exist.

My question is this: how can I repair my beloved mysql auto-complete by removing this phantom table? I would assume (wrongly?) that auto-complete suggestions within the mysql command line are drawn from a table within mysql. Where can I go to zap this safely - or do I just need to man up and get used to typing the entire table name?

Comment: Is `widget_date` the name of one of your table columns, perchance?

Comment: It is, but it shows up in the omitted portions `[... columns on widget_signups ...]` as `widget_signup.widget_date`

Comment: Thought as much. The auto-complete isn't context aware, thus causing the issue that's distressing you :)

Comment: Ahhhhhhh. That makes perfect sense. Make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the auto-complete isn't context aware & it's offering you a column name of `widget_date` as well as the table name you're expecting.